# jax rs multidimensional array like param

Tags: multidimensional-array, jax-rs, query-string

I have the next object in java script:

```
var customObj = [];
customObj[customId] = {name:'sample',other:'other'};
customObj[customId2] = {name:'sample2',other:'other2'};
```

when i try to parse on a query params results in something like this:

> customObj[0][name]=sample&customObj[0][other]=other&customObj[1][name]=sample2&customObj[1][other]=other2

In jax rs i have this resource:

```
@GET
public MyObject getSomething(@QueryParam("customObj") customObj /*Here is the problem*/){
  for(ObjectOrMapOrListOrArrayList myObject:customObject){
      System.out.println(myObject);//prints something like {name:'sample',other:'other'}
  }
}
```

But i don't know how to recive the object param, i try using List> because in my object all data is a string but it doesn't work, i try using Map but i recive

**incorrect parameter type error**

.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the String and parse it to a JsonOnbject.

```
@GET
public MyObject getSomething(@QueryParam("customObj")String customObj ){
  JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(customobj));
  JsonObject object = jsonReader.readObject();
  jsonReader.close();
  ...
}
```

Note that this is `javax.json`